# Problems w. read.csv, error message: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : scan() expected 'a real', got

Tags: r, read.csv

I get a repeated error message (below) when trying to import a CSV-file with data, and there has been no problems previous years when using exactly the same R-script and the read.csv-command. I get the impression this is a common problem, and the usual advice is to use read.csv rather than scan, but as I have done this I am stuck and would be grateful for information.

Here is the script:

#Read in all individual data for the year to be updated

```
Idata <- read.csv("Exp3.csv", sep = ";", header = T,
     colClasses=c("numeric", rep("character",4), rep("factor",8), "numeric",
                           "factor", rep("numeric",11), "factor"))
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
scan() expected 'a real', got '63991,21.1074,Ischnura,elegans,06/20    
/21,HojeA14,1074,0,mature,1,1073,blue,,0,androchrome,,,,,,,,,,,2021,KP'
```

Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I would recommend just using ``fread`` from the data.table library - it's much quicker and it figured out all the colClasses for you etc.

Comment: Can you please include a link to a (subset of) your CSV file, to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the separator argument. In `read.csv` it's coded as `;` but the data is *comma*-separated.